# Error connected to log4j in case of compilation of the hadoop program

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, compilation, log4j

I wrote hadoop the program with use of log4j and I give its part

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class ParallelIndexation {
    //public static native long Traveser(String Path);

    //public static native void Configure(String Path);

    //static {
    //  System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
    //}
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Map.class.getName());
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
```

I tried to compile the hadoop-program by means of a command

```
root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin#. / javac - classpath/export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar - d/folder/classes/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java
```

also I received as a result the following error messages

```
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: <identifier> expected
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
                                 ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: illegal start of type
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
                                  ^
2 errors
```

Help to eliminate these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");
```

should be in a method (or constructor or `static` initializer)

rather than in the class block of `Map`